# Angular: uib accordion + uib pagination

Tags: angularjs

I need spme help, please! 
I have a list of accordions to paginate. I have an example how to paginate `<ul>` : http://plnkr.co/edit/AD1AGCYIm1dZhbuoPhxX?p=preview 
But when I try to do similar to accordion instead of `<ul>` I get an error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`  
http://plnkr.co/edit/rwqZiR?p=preview 
Who knows what's wrong?

Or maybe there's someone else solution without promises?

Answer (score 0):

In your example.js file, `$scope.items` is defined as an array of objects, it's not a promise.
It falls on trying to read the `$promise` property of an array (which doesn't exist).

Comment: See in the first plunker 'friends.json', here's also an array of objects

Comment: Yes but it's accessed via `friendsFactory.query()` which returns a promise. In the second example you have the array hard-coded in the JS file. You should access it using an http request like in the first example.

Comment: I made some changes: http://plnkr.co/edit/4FAPel?p=preview but accordions don't still paginate